Impact of South African visa validity on Schengen visa application
I'm seeking guidance about an important step in my journey. As a spouse of a permanent resident with a spousal visa expiring in March, I’m excited about the possibility of applying for a Schengen visa in January. I have a new passport valid for the next four years, while my old passport, tied to my current visa, will expire in March as well. I wonder if France would grant me a 21-day visa despite my South African visa being valid for just a month after leaving the Schengen area.

How stable is your situation in South Africa? Do you need to apply for a renewal of this spousal visa or some sort of other status?

How do you have a new passport at the same time as an old one that is about to expire?  Are they from two different countries?  If they are from the same country, doesn't the old one become invalidated when you receive the new one?

@AriBrodsky one can have two valid passports from the same country, and I also don't see how this relates to the actual question. OP's old passport being invalid or not shouldn't affect the answer.

It is lawful to apply for a new passport no earlier than 6 months, and I have successfully renewed my spousal visa, although I don't when I will get it. My main concern is regarding the Schengen rule, which states that a passport must have at least 3 months of validity remaining upon returning to your residential country. I need clarification on whether this rule also applies to visas.

If you apply for a Schengen visa, no matter what, I'd definitely attach a letter stating your situation in clear words, not going into unnecessary detail about the dual passports (Simply that you are married to a ZA citizen, that you live in ZA, that your current visa will expire not long after your expected return, and that you have renewed your visa but not received it yet. This should communicate that you have continued interest in living in ZA with your spouse, reducing your risk profile.).
